# Cambiar dimensiones con Numpy

Tags: array, numpy, plot

estoy tratando de sacar la envolvente de unas señales, es un arreglo de (512,8) pero el código que pude observar solo te da la envolvente de un arreglo de (512,).

Lo que puedo hacer es sacar una envolvente pero de una sola señal que es de dimensión (512,) pero no he podido hacer es sacar la envolvente de las 8 jutas.

Igual si se pudiera cambiar la dimensión del arreglo que pase de (512,8) a (512,), seria de gran ayuda o si se pudieran como empalmar las señales para que de igual forma solo este trabajando con un arreglo de una dimensión.

Aquí les muestro el código, espero y alguien me pueda ayudar.

Saludos, que tengan un excelente día.

###################################################

```
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pylab import * 
import matplotlib.lines as lines

datos = pd.read_csv('dedo.csv', header=None)
print(datos)

    **0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    ...   502  \
0   5.0   1.0  -7.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   2.0   0.0 -11.0  -1.0  ... -15.0   
1  -6.0   9.0 -20.0  10.0   4.0   7.0  -6.0 -18.0   6.0   0.0  ...  -4.0   
2  -4.0  61.0 -84.0  59.0  38.0  18.0 -67.0 -61.0 -27.0   5.0  ...   1.0   
3 -10.0   7.0 -23.0  17.0  -5.0   7.0  -1.0 -30.0   8.0  12.0  ...   4.0   
4  -2.0  -4.0  -1.0   5.0  -2.0   2.0   0.0  -4.0  -6.0   5.0  ...   2.0   
5   1.0 -15.0   9.0   4.0   1.0  -5.0  -2.0  -1.0  -7.0   3.0  ...  -2.0   
6 -14.0  -9.0  12.0   9.0  -3.0  -8.0  10.0  -5.0 -10.0   3.0  ... -25.0   
7   0.0  -7.0   5.0   8.0  -5.0  -3.0   4.0  -2.0  -4.0   0.0  ... -24.0   
    503   504   505   506   507  508  509   510   511  
0   8.0  -6.0   4.0  -3.0  15.0  2.0 -1.0 -10.0  -7.0  
1  -3.0 -16.0  17.0 -12.0   4.0 -7.0  1.0   1.0  -3.0  
2 -26.0 -12.0  33.0  24.0 -24.0  7.0 -6.0  -7.0   3.0  
3   0.0 -24.0   8.0  10.0 -10.0  1.0 -6.0   8.0  -2.0  
4   0.0 -10.0   0.0  -3.0   1.0  2.0  1.0  -1.0  -3.0  
5   7.0  -3.0  -1.0  -2.0   6.0  4.0 -1.0   0.0  -6.0  
6   5.0 -14.0   6.0  12.0   0.0 -3.0 -3.0  -2.0 -12.0  
7   6.0 -13.0  12.0  -4.0  10.0 -5.0  1.0 -15.0 -16.0  
[8 rows x 512 columns]**


uno=(datos2[0,:])
dos=(datos2[1,:])
tres=(datos2[2,:])
cuatro=(datos2[3,:])
cinco=(datos2[4,:])
seis=(datos2[5,:])
siete=(datos2[6,:])
ocho=(datos2[7,:])

vector = np.column_stack((uno,dos,tres,cuatro,cinco,seis,siete,ocho))

figure(num=None, figsize=(30, 6), dpi=200, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.plot(vector)
```

[image: La imagen representa las 8 señales del archivo]

```
def hl_envelopes_idx(s,dmin=1,dmax=1):
    """
    s : 1d-array, data signal from which to extract high and low envelopes
    dmin, dmax : int, size of chunks, use this if size of data is too big
    """

    # locals min      
    lmin = (np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(s))) > 0).nonzero()[0] + 1 
    # locals max
    lmax = (np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(s))) < 0).nonzero()[0] + 1

    """
    # the following might help in some case by cutting the signal in "half"
    s_mid = np.mean(s) (0 if s centered or more generally mean of signal)
    # pre-sort of locals min based on sign 
    lmin = lmin[s[lmin]<s_mid]
    # pre-sort of local max based on sign 
    lmax = lmax[s[lmax]>s_mid]
    """

    # global max of dmax-chunks of locals max 
    lmin = lmin[[i+np.argmin(s[lmin[i:i+dmin]]) for i in range(0,len(lmin),dmin)]]
    # global min of dmin-chunks of locals min 
    lmax = lmax[[i+np.argmax(s[lmax[i:i+dmax]]) for i in range(0,len(lmax),dmax)]]

    return lmin,lmax

t = np.linspace(8,120*np.pi,512,endpoint=True)
s = vector
high_idx, low_idx = hl_envelopes_idx(s)

# plot
figure(num=None, figsize=(30, 6), dpi=200, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.plot(t,s,label='signal')
plt.plot(t[high_idx], s[high_idx], 'r', label='low')
plt.plot(t[low_idx], s[low_idx], 'g', label='high')
```

Comment: Como poder, se puede pasar, otra cosa es que obtengas el resultado esperado. puedes pasar (512, 8) a un vector, pero no sería de 512, sería de 512*8. Creo que la pregunta que te tienes que hacer es. ¿En que formato mis datos estarían correctos? Averiguar la respuesta y después programar. Tengo la sensación de que estás buscando como cambiar dimensiones aunque no tenga sentido, para los datos que usas.

Answer (score 0):

Cambiar dimensiones con `numpy` es sencillo, tan solo tienes que usar el método `.reshape()`. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np

#Creamos una matriz ejemplo de unos, de dos dimensiones (3,3)
matriz_3_3 = np.ones([3,3])

#Como es 3*3 lo podríamos pasar a una dimensión, siendo un vector de 9 números (9,).
print(np.ones([3,3]).reshape(9))
```

Como puedes ver, si haces un reshape de (512, 8) te van a quedar un vector de (4096,). Lo que a priri dudo que funcione con tus datos.

**En conclusión, es imposible** pasar una matriz de (512,8) a (512,) sin perder información.